# Existing mail viewer window doesn't open when I click on Mail App dock icon

Tags: mail.app

I have minimised a mail viewer window to the dock. When I click the Mail icon (to the left of the dividing line) it does not bring the viewer window up. I have to click on the actual viewer window (to the right of the line) to see the window and mail messages. This is new, reverts to normal if I close mail and restart, but soon reverts. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem but it went away when I removed mail from the dock and then docked it again.

Right click icon, select options, uncheck "Keep in Dock"

Right click icon, select quit

Then start mail from Finder>Applications and recheck "Keep in Dock" from the icon that reappears in the dock

Comment: I have exactly the same question. I have looked around, in particular at several suggestion on Discussions Apple. Nothing works. Occasionally, clicking on the Mail Icon works and then it stops working. (10.6.8)

Comment: This happened to me on 10.12.Sierra. The other way you can do this is just dragging the icon out of the dock then quit the application (if it's not already closed) then re-add it to the dock from the Applications folder. I'm not sure if this will solve the problem. This is just an alternative method of the same process mentioned by Geoffrey.